# Get byte [] from file in ZIP

Tags: java, zip

I nees to get a file from *.zip as byte array. I do this

```
String zipFileLocation = pathToFile;


File file = new File(zipFileLocation);
ZipFile zipfile = new ZipFile(file);

ZipEntry zipentry;

System.out.println("nList of files in zip archive");
int fileNumber = 0;
for (Enumeration<? extends ZipEntry> e = zipfile.entries(); 
e.hasMoreElements(); fileNumber++) {
zipentry = e.nextElement();

if (!zipentry.isDirectory()) {
   System.out.println(fileNumber + "-" + zipentry.getName());
 }
} 

for (Enumeration<? extends ZipEntry> e = zipfile.entries(); e.hasMoreElements(); ) {
zipentry = e.nextElement();
 if (!zipentry.isDirectory()) {
    fileName  = zipentry.getName();
 InputStream input = zipfile.getInputStream(zipentry);
 BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(input, "UTF-8"));
 (hash map) nameANDbytes.put(fileName, br.toString().getBytes());
}
```

lets say, that I get

```
 [B@8f2ef19
```

but when I unzip file and do :

```
String pathToCheckingFile = "path_to_file";
        byte[] b = {};
        try {
        RandomAccessFile f = new RandomAccessFile(pathToCheckingFile, "r");
        b = new byte[(int) f.length()];
        f.read(b);
    }catch(FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }catch(IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

        System.out.println(b);
```

I get :

```
 [B@2cf3d63b
```

What's wrong?

Besides if I do last fragment of code several times - I always ged different results.

Comment: They are pointing to different byte arrays, that is all. You should check, what the actual content of both arrays is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following code to get the Bytes or the String :

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    ZipFile zipFile = new ZipFile("C:/Test/Test.zip");
    Enumeration<? extends ZipEntry> entries = zipFile.entries();

    while(entries.hasMoreElements()){
        ZipEntry entry = entries.nextElement();
        System.out.println(entry.getName());
        InputStream stream = zipFile.getInputStream(entry);

        //For characters
        //BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream));
        BufferedInputStream reader = new BufferedInputStream(stream);
        //For line reading
        //System.out.println(reader.readLine());
        int byteRead = reader.read();
        while(byteRead != -1) {
            System.out.println(byteRead);
            byteRead = reader.read();
        }

    }
}
```

The one you are seeing is simply the object that is instantiated every time you run it and toString represents the unsigned hexadecimal representation of the hash code of the object

Answer (score 0):

`BufferedReader.toString()` doesnt perform any I/O. If you want the contents of the stream you have to read them. `BufferedReader` isn't appropriate anyway unless you know the file is text.

Answer (score 0):

Here first we can covert our zip file to simple file object.
Apache commons library IOUtils have in-built function for do same stuff.

```
ZipFile zipFile = new ZipFile(convertMultiPartToFile(file)
byte[] bytes = IOUtils.readAllBytes(zipFile.getInputStream(entry));
```

Comment: add some explanation to your answer

Comment: Sure, but i think it's self explainatory